# How I can get rid of specified fields while creating proxy for a WCF service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wsdl, datacontractserializer

While creating proxy from a WCF service,the each value type members which I declared inside service creating one more bool type specified field in proxy. Is there any way i can get rid of this and continue to transact with service?

i have below class described in service as

```
[DataContract]
public class Customer
{
    private int customerID;

    [DataMember]
    public int CustomerID
    {
        get { return customerID; }
        set { customerID = value; }
    }
}
```

while creating proxy i am having proxy class like this

```
public partial class Customer
{
     private int customerIDField;

     private bool customerIDFieldSpecified;
     public int CustomerID 
     {
         get { return this.customerIDField; }
         set { this.customerIDField = value; }
     }
}
```

How i can get rid of customerIDFieldSpecified bool type member in proxy? and also how can i continue with service by only setting customerIDField.

I wanted my proxy class to be like this

```
public partial class Customer
{
     private int customerIDField;
     public int CustomerID 
     {
         get{ return this.customerIDField; }
         set{ this.customerIDField = value; }
     }
}
```

Comment: Unclear. Try to add code for how it's now and for how you would like it to be.

Comment: Here, I need to make that specified member(customerIDFieldSpecified) to "true" to work on this.

Comment: OK, that is a lot clearer now. I don't have a direct answer but that field looks rather harmless, do you actual problems? And I'm surprised the setter doesn't set it.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of those fields?

Comment: I need to convert the same object (without specified fields) which is already referenced in my client application. These specified fields making things more complex while i am trying to convert.

Answer (score 6):

> How i can get rid of customerIDFieldSpecified bool type member in
>   proxy?

It used to be common with ASMX web services for class members of type bool, int, decimal, or any XSD compatible value type exposed over the service boundary to have an equivalent `...FieldSpecified` property defined in addition to the actual field to contain the value.

The reason this was put into generated proxy code is quite simple: that when the XmlSerializer serializes types to XML, and because in .net these types (if they are not specified) return [default values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx), the resulting message payload would contain a bool or decimal/int/etc field with a value false or 0 respectively.

Now, if you omit a value in a type and then this type gets serialized and set to it's default value, then this is undesirable, because default values are actual values, which is misleading and will cause defects. So to get around this the `...FieldSpecified` property was introduced.

The idea was that if you wanted the field to be included, you also had to set the equivalent FieldSpecified property to true, and that would instruct the XmlSerializer on the service side to deserialize (and therefore assign) the values into the server's representation of the type. If this was not specified then the XmlSerializer would skip the equivalent property and just move onto the next field in the XML.

With WCF, Microsoft introduced the DataContractSerializer, as a replacement for the XmlSerializer. The DataContractSerializer does not exhibit the same behavior on deserialization and will not try to assign any value to fields not present in the XML, so this extra field is no longer needed. However, under certain conditions, WCF falls back on the XmlSerializer when it's generating client code from service metadata, which is my guess as to how you ended up with them.

Comment: Having seen this a few times, I've always wondered about why it was there.  Thanks for the explanation (and congrats on your recent silver WCF badge as well :)).