# Custom data-type not serialized to XML

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf, serialization

In VS2012 (C#, .Net 4.5) I'm consuming a third-party WebService by adding a service reference from the Solution Explorer (the content of the auto-generated Reference.cs file is attached).

When I invoke a method of the WebService for inserting an object of this class, the first field is serialized to XML correctly, as the second field (custom) is ignored.

But, when I invoke another method to query for an object of this class (previously inserted using soapUI, which tells me the WebService is running ok), I can receive and handle correctly both fields (which means the deserialization process is well performed, I think).

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34209")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://es/mynamespace")]
public partial class AccidenteRequest : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private string descripcionField;       
    private AccidenteRequestSalida_via salida_viaField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public string descripcion {
        get {
            return this.descripcionField;
        }
        set {
            this.descripcionField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("descripcion");
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 1)]
    public AccidenteRequestSalida_via salida_via {
        get {
            return this.salida_viaField;
        }
        set {
            this.salida_viaField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("salida_via");
        }
    }
}

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool salida_viaSpecified {
        get {
            return this.salida_viaFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.salida_viaFieldSpecified = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("salida_viaSpecified");
        }
    }

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34209")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://es/mynamespace")]
public enum AccidenteRequestSalida_via {
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("0")]
    Item0,

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("1")]
    Item1,
}
```

At the XSD file, those fields are:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="descripcion">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="2000" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="salida_via">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:enumeration value="0" />
            <xs:enumeration value="1" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

I assign a value to the field this way:

```
accidente.salida_via = AccidenteRequestSalida_via.Item1;
```

But I can't see that value in the final XML sent to the WebService.

Given this:
UPDATE: By default, C# seems to start enums from 0. It's possible to do something like:
    accidente.circula_sentido_contrario = (AccidenteRequestCircula_sentido_contrario)VALUE_FROM_DB

VALUE_FROM_DB comes from database, and I need it to have the same value as the String in XmlEnumAttribute. Now I have to assign 0 and then is translated to Item1, but I need to assign 1.

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34209")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="somenamespace")]
public enum AccidenteRequestCircula_sentido_contrario {

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("1")]
    Item1,
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What serializer is used?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov - Based on the posted code, XmlSerializer.

Comment: @Tim - Yes, based on it should be XmlSerializer, but who knows what uses author.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I think it's XmlSerializer. How can I include the second (custom) field into the serialization?

Comment: Is there a accidente.salida_viaSpecified property too?

Comment: @TomRedfern Yes. Question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the relevant *Specified* field to true.

```
accidente.salida_via = AccidenteRequestSalida_via.Item1;
accidente.salida_viaSpecified = true;
```

Explaination can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30604168/569662

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm! :D